# How do i manage system SystemStackError (stack level too deep): rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.1

1. How i can resolve the system stack too deep?

   Model:

   ```
   class Testimony < ApplicationRecord
             belongs_to :user
             before_create :randomize_id
              scope :published, ->{ where(:published => true)}
             has_one_attached :picture
             has_one_attached :video
             #scope :unpublished, where(published: false)
           private 
           def randomize_id
             begin
               self.id = SecureRandom.random_number(1_000_000_000)
             end while Testimony.where(id: self.id).exists?
           end  

           end

           User Model:
           class User < ApplicationRecord

       #attr_accessible :email, :password
           include JsonWebToken
           #searchkick
           #paginates_per 10
           #before_create :create_username
           # before_save  :set_authentication_token
       before_create :randomize_id
       after_save :generate_authentication_token

       has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy
       has_many :testimonies, dependent: :destroy
       has_many :services, dependent: :destroy
       has_many :branches, dependent: :destroy
       has_many :songs, dependent: :destroy
       has_many :choirs, dependent: :destroy
       has_many :members, dependent: :destroy
       has_many :lives, dependent: :destroy
       has_many :replies, dependent: :destroy
       has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
       #has_one_attached :picture


       This is what i get:

        User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
         CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
       Big Man
       "this user exists ashanamanya123@gmail.com"
         Testimony Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "testimonies".* FROM "testimonies" LIMIT ? OFFSET ?  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
          (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "testimonies"
       [active_model_serializers]   ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_attachments".* FROM
   ```

   "active_storage_attachments" WHERE
   "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = ? AND
   "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = ? AND
   "active_storage_attachments"."name" = ? LIMIT ?  [["record_id",
   936404], ["record_type", "Testimony"], ["name", "video"], ["LIMIT",
   1]]
   [active_model_serializers] Rendered ActiveModel::Serializer::Null with Hash (17.64ms)
   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 91ms (ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)
   SystemStackError (stack level too deep):